# copy to android system clipboard in nvim from termux

Tags: android, neovim, termux, clipboard-interaction

I use neovim on termux on android 11
i commonly use `:y` to yank/copy text to nvim clipboard

then paste it to another files

recently I've tried using [helix-editor](https://helix-editor.com)(hx) looks and feels so similar to neovim(with nvchad/spacevim) with a bunch of themes

in its normal mode there is a command `:clipboard-yank`
which literally **Yank main selection into system clipboard.** after selection of required text.

and similar function is also available on tmux too..

but in nvim it doesn't copy to system clipboard

i tried searching for this function and fond some solutions but those didnt worked for me

```lua
set clipboard=unnamed
set clipboard=unnamedplus
set clipboard+=unnamed
```

or these `"*y` `"+y`

so, is thre any way to copy to system clipboard

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Install termux-api and you will have termux-clipboard-get and termux-clipboard-set. I also had to uninstall xclip

If you run `:h clipboard` you will get:

```
                                  *clipboard-tool*
The presence of a working clipboard tool implicitly enables the '+' and '*'
registers. Nvim looks for these clipboard tools, in order of priority:

  - |g:clipboard|
  - pbcopy, pbpaste (macOS)
  - wl-copy, wl-paste (if $WAYLAND_DISPLAY is set)
  - waycopy, waypaste (if $WAYLAND_DISPLAY is set)
  - xclip (if $DISPLAY is set)
  - xsel (if $DISPLAY is set)
  - lemonade (for SSH) https://github.com/pocke/lemonade
  - doitclient (for SSH) https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/doit/
  - win32yank (Windows)
  - termux (via termux-clipboard-set, termux-clipboard-set)
  - tmux (if $TMUX is set)
```

All you have to do is make sure you have termux-clipboard and remove xclip

Answer (score 0):

**see here this actually works**

- install [termux-api](https://termuxapi.en.uptodown.com/android)
- also in termux `pkg install termux-api`
- test it: `termux-clipboard-set "text"` and `termux-clipboard-get`
- add this line to your .vimrc or init.vim : `set clipboard+=unnamedplus`